# prove that $\int_0^1 (x-f(x))dx \leq 1-4b(1-a)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality, contest-math

> Source: 2013 UofT competition, problem 3.

> Let $f(x)$ be a convex increasing real-valued function defined on the closed interval $[0,1]$ for which $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$. Suppose $0<a<1 $ and $b =f(a)$. Prove that $\int_0^1 (x-f(x))dx \leq 1-4b(1-a)$.

Note that the inequality can be rewritten as $\int_0^1 f(x)dx \ge 2b(1-a).$
Note also that $a\leq b$ since $f$ must lie on or below the line $y=x$ due to convexity. Indeed, for any convex function $g$ and points $(a,g(a))$ and $(b,g(b))$, g must lie on or below the line through $(a,g(a))$ and $(b,g(b))$, which has the equation $y(x) = g(b) + \dfrac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a} (x - b)$ (1). This is because for a point $(x, g(b) + \dfrac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a} (x - b))$ on the line where $a\leq x\leq b$, $x = a+t(b-a)$ for some $t\in [0,1]$, namely $t = \dfrac{x-a}{b-a}.$ So by convexity, $g(x) \leq (1-t)g(a) + tg(b) = \dfrac{b-x}{b-a} g(a) + \dfrac{x-a}{b-a} g(b) = y(x).$ Take $a=0, b=1, g=f$ to see that $f$ lies on or below the line through $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, which has the equation $y=x$.

In a part of the solution, they proceeded as follows.

Note that $f$ is continuous, as proved in the first part of the original question. First, we claim that for $0\leq u < x < v \leq 1$, we have $\dfrac{f(x)-f(u)}{x-u}\leq \dfrac{f(v)-f(x)}{v-x}$. We have $(v-u)x=(v-x)u + (x-u)v$ and $(v-x) f(x)+(x-u)f(x)=(v-u)f(x)\leq (v-x)f(u) + (x-u)f(v)$ (where the inequality holds by the convexity of f). The result then follows by algebraic manipulation. Let $m$ be any number between the supremum s of the LHS over $u<x$ and the infimum i of the RHS over $v >x$, which exists because $s\leq i$ (by taking the supremum of the LHS first and then the infimum of the RHS). Clearly $m\ge 0$ since f is increasing. The line $L(x)=m(x-a)+b$ contains the points $(a-b/m,0)$ and $(1,m(1-a)+b)$.

> I think it's possible that either $a-b/m$ or $m(1-a)+b$  may not be in $[0,1]$. But clearly $a-b/m < 1$. Suppose however that $m$ is instead taken as any number between the infimum of the RHS when $x=a$ and the supremum of the LHS when $x=a$. Then we necessarily have $\dfrac{f(a)-f(0)}{a-0} = \dfrac{f(a)}a \leq m\Rightarrow a-b/m\ge 0$ and $m(1-a) + b \ge \dfrac{f(1)-f(a)}{1-a}(1-a) + b = 1.$ The point $(a,f(a))$ is on line $L$ and so by the convexity of $f,$ if the graph of $f$ shares a point $(x,f(x))$ with $L$ where $x\neq a,$ . Since $f(1) - L(1) \leq 0$ and $f(a) = L(a).$ By convexity (or technically (1)), $f$ lies on or below the line $L_2$ between $(a,f(a))$ and $(1,1)$, and $L_2$ lies on or below $L$ since L has a slope that's at least that of $L_2$.

> Why is it true that just because f is convex, the line can't contain any point of the graph of $f$ other than $(a,f(a))$? We have by the definition of convexity that $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda )y)\leq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda )f(y)$. If $(x,f(x))$ is on the line, then we have $f(x)-f(a)=m(x-a).$ For $x\neq a$ this implies $\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = m.$ There's also condition (1) mentioned at the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is allowed to be assumed for such a problem, but the left-hand and right-hand derivatives exist at $a$ due to $f$ being convex. So if you choose any line through $(a, b)$ with slope $m$ satisfying $f'_-(a) \leq m \leq f'_+(a)$, the graph will lie entirely on or above this line.

Consequently, the triangle with sides $y = 0$, $x = 1$, and this line lies entirely below the graph and has area $2a(1 - b)$. Hence $\int_0^1 f(x)$ is at least this.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but it seems you're mostly repeating the info from the solution, which I have access to. The point of my question was to better understand the solution to the question. For one, could you further justify why the left- and right- hand sides exist at a due to f being convex? Also, why will the graph lie entirely on or above any line through $(a,b)$ with slope m satisfying the given inequality?

Comment: Google is your friend. For the first, you can see the proof at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Convex_Real_Function_is_Left-Hand_and_Right-Hand_Differentiable For the second, if  say $c > a$, then using ${f(c) - f(a) \over c -a} \geq {f(x) - f(a) \over x - a}$ for $a < x < c$ (you can google this also) and taking limits as $x$ goes to $a$ you get that $f(c)$ must be on or above this line. Similar if $c < a$.